# Possible to have Wordpress and Woocommerce on their own folders?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

I'm in a bit of a pickle... Is it possible to do this if Wordpress is in a folder?

Forum:
domain.com

Wordpress:
domain.com/blog

Woocommerce:
domain.com/store

My main domain has a forum running on it so I can't put Wordpress in there.
So it's in `domain.com/blog` and the store is `domain.com/blog/store` or `domain.com/blog/product` which I don't want. 
Please help me!

Any sort of solution is welcome.

Comment: Why is this a problem at all? Just install the Wordpress site in the sub directory you desire.

Comment: Can't you read? I can't do it that way.

Comment: I've never heard of the rule where you can't put a subdirectory in because there is a forum running there. But if you think you can't do that, then why don't you put it somewhere else and call it `store.domain.com` and `product.domain.com`. `blog/store` doesn't even make sense. What is a blog store?

Comment: I want it out of the subdirectory. I have a blog AND a store but it's showing as /blog/store because I can't seperate them and I don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, but I think you have 2 choices:

1. A [multisite](/questions/tagged/multisite) [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) installation:
   You can manage 2 web sites In one Wordpress installation. 
   Each web site will have his own URL. 
   Reference: [Wordpress MultiSite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)
2. You can Also have 2 separate [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) Installations:
   The first one can contain the second one (I have already done that with a [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)/[woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce) [production](/questions/tagged/production) website, containing a [test](/questions/tagged/test) website for SSL certificate reasons).

---

Update:

3. You can set all WooCommerce pages as subpages of your WooCommerce Shop (store) page. When WooCommerce is installed, it creates 4 pages: You Will rename 'Shop' page in 'Store'. You will make all 3 other pages, subpages of 'Store' page. Then you will have to edit all `end points urls` and some WooCommerce `permalinks`. You might need to use some redirection rules too in `.htaccess` file.
    The only problem is that you will have `domain.com/blog/store/` as main url for all woocommerce stuff, because your main wordpress install is `domain.com/blog/`.

Comment: Could I do url rewriting perhaps? Also how do you do that?

I really don't want more than one install. They need a standalone option for Woocommerce.

Comment: That's what I want to get out of...is there any way I can run Wordpress from the same directory as the forum (It's SMF if that makes a difference) and have it serve the blogs on /blog and store on /store but show the forum by default?